# What is $(p-1)!$ mod $(1 + 2 + \cdots + (p-1))$ where $p$ is an odd prime? (Exam Q)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've done a bit of fiddling and I believe the answer to be $(p-1)$ but I don't know how to prove it. The first part of the question asks what $1^p + 2^p + \cdots + (p-1)^p$ is modulo $p$ and it comes out as $1 + 2 + \dots + (p-1) \equiv 0 \ (mod \ p)$ but I'm not sure if it's related or not. Other than this, all I have is Wilson's theorem. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

$$1+2+\ldots+p-1=\frac{(p-1)p}2\implies (p-1)!=p-1\pmod{\frac{(p-1)p}2}\iff$$

$$(p-1)\left((p-2)!-1\right)=0\pmod{\frac{(p-1)p}2}$$

But Wilson's Theorem gives us

$$(p-1)!=-1\pmod p\implies(p-2)!=\frac{(p-1)!}{p-1}=\frac{-1}{-1}=1\pmod p\implies\ldots$$

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you meant but going from $(p-2)! = 1 \pmod p$ I went into the integers i.e. $(p-2)! = np + 1$ and then multiplied by $\frac{p-1}{2}$ to get the answer - I think that works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, that's precisely the meaning fo that, @JosephML: $$(p-2)!=1\pmod p\iff \;\exists, n\in\Bbb Z\;\;s.t. (p-2)!=1 + np$$

Comment: Doesn't your first implication line solves the problem? (in a very, very implicit way)

Comment: Well, yes @chubakueno...because $\;\frac{p-1}2\;$ is an integer....:)

Answer (score 0):

Well I assume your question is finding $(p-1)!\equiv ? \left(\mod {\frac{p(p-1)}{2}}\right)$. Well I think CRT works.
Now see that $(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod p$ and $(p-1)!\equiv 0\pmod {p-1}$
and since $\text{gcd}(p,p-1)=1$ CRT works nicely. But I am not gonna give the complete solution since I might make calculation mistakes which I probably did so I am editing it.
Urghhh why am I such a failure.Please do not mind my mistakes.
EDIT:I am sorry for posting such a misleading thing please forgive me.

Comment: Oh darn I am such a dumbo.I use $n\mid n!$ which is trivially true.Anyways thanks a lot for pointing that out Eppo.I will edit it.